# Why does Bayern & 1868 cause an argument in this Transglobal Underground song?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In the song 'Drinking in Gomorrah' (Impossible Broadcasting, 2004) by [Transglobal Underground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transglobal_Underground) there is this lyric:

> And it's quiet except for this couple of German cotton buyers, who both turn out to come from Munich, and get into a heated row about relative merits of Bayern and 1868, when they get a bit too loud, I move in, calm things down, make a couple crap jokes.

(There seems to be some disagreement on the *actual* lyrics on the internet lyrics sites but I'm *pretty* sure what I've put above are correct)

So, what is the relevance of 'Bayern' and '1868' ?
I'm assuming that it's going to be personal to people from Germany (and maybe even Munich) ?

Full song here : [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n387r0gW4HQ)

Comment: I'm not sure, whether this question is not more related to history, but there seems a connection to [Zollverein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zollverein),  
which reasonably matches cotton (obviously related to custom charges) buyers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've got the answer. I went direct to source and asked Transglobal Underground (via Facebook)...

Here's what they wrote:

> I once knew a cotton buyer from Munich who worked in Cairo and didn’t like Bayern so I thought Id put him in the story. Onstage the lyric would refer to wherever we were at the time….the doors to the bar opened everywhere

> The reference to 1868 should have been 1860, which shows what I know about German football.

So the reference is entirely *football* based as it refers to two clubs from Munich, [Bayern Munich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Bayern_Munich) and [1860 Munich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSV_1860_Munich) and their rivalry.

[The Munich Derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_derby)